# Using more than one provider in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have started using PROVIDER to manage state in my app. I followed tutorials and wrapped my Material app with ChangeNotifierProvider.
Here's the code :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => ListsProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'WordsApp',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: StartingPage.id,
        routes: {
          StartingPage.id: (context) => StartingPage(),
         
          RegistrationScreen.id: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
        
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This provider called "ListsProvider" takes care of "providing" lists that need to be displayed on different screens.
I have now created a second provider which I called "user_data_provider" and I now need to add it to my app too. It will take care of providing user data to many different screens.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achive this you can use `Multiprovider` as shown below

Add this to the top of your app. If you need these obj everywhere.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<user_data_provider>(
          create: (_) => user_data_provider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ListsProvider>(
          create: (_) => ListsProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          
          return MaterialApp(
            //YOur code goes here
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: This is perfect :) Thank you very much for your help !!